# URL frame breaks responsive website

Tags: html, css, url, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation to create a single page responsive website. The page is located at foo.com/event.php but I have a separate domain (event.com) with a url frame record pointing to foo.com/event.php page. 
Here is the issue: when I visit foo.com/event.php on iOS, the mobile optimized version is correctly shown. But when I visit event.com, the desktop version loads. Somehow, the url frame is breaking the responsiveness. 
Strangely, If I visit event.com on a desktop browser, I can make the responsive layout kick in by resizing the window.

How do I solve this issue? Please keep in mind that I have little knowledge about js and css media queries.

Comment: Frame? As in `<frame>`, you're still using frames? They were deprecated years ago...

Answer (score 9):

I stumbled upon this problem today, it's kinda weird that some companies delivers webapps based around a frameset in order to work. Sadly it's up to me to do the best of the situation. Anyway my solution to this was to simply add this meta-tag in the head of the top-page containing the frameset:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```